# Sitecore as a content repository for public and private marketing content

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, taxonomy

We are implementing Sitecore as our CMS and it will handle the company's website and public-facing marketing content such as landing pages, white papers, etc.

We also own and use a lot of sales enablement documents (presentations, briefs) and we'd like to use Sitecore as a single-location content repository for easy access, version control, and content auditing and tracking purposes.

Does Sitecore allow us to securely tag non-public content as private so that only internal/approved users can search and access the sales-enablement content?

Comment: yes, you are able to build solution with different levels of access for different groups of users.

Comment: Sitecore is probably not the best tool to use as a document management system, there are plenty more better purpose-built solutions for this,

Comment: @jammykam Is there a system that you would recommend? Thanks!

Comment: Not my area of expertise unfortunately, but we use [Sharepoint Online](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-collaboration-software) internally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can find security related information here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/the_security_tools

As you will see, you can (should) use roles to define the security (who gets to see what) and add users to the roles. The search api's from Sitecore will use the security as well. As media items are content as well in Sitecore, this applies to those as well.

Be aware that a complex security can become troublesome if you don't take it into account from the start. As you have this information already, use it in your (content) architecture. Setting security on folders is much easier than on individual items ;)